# How to compress images at build time

Tags: angular, image-processing, google-cloud-storage, imagemin

1. In angular which npm package should i use to compress image (assets) at build time and also upload it to server

TYIA

Comment: There are several questions in your question and your main pain point is blury. What's not working for now?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/70658960/6666348 and https://medium.com/@daveahern/automatically-optimizing-images-in-angular-833a65c7fcf9